# Stringify behaves strangely when applied to a dictionary in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, dictionary

I am using a dictionary to register the statuses of a number of appliances and I would like to convert them to JSON to be archived.
This is the code I use to build the dictionary:

```
$scope.lastValues=[];
    for (var i in nomeImpianti) {
        var newValue={
            id: i,
                name: nomeImpianti[i],
            values:{
                value1: true,
                        value2: false,
                        value3: false
            }
        }
        $scope.lastValues[nomeImpianti[i]]=0;
    }
```

Yet when I print the array it appears in the form:

> [general: 0, motore 1: 0, motore 2: 0, impianto 1: 0, impianto 2:
>   0...]

Instead of the form with the {} typical of javascript dictionaries.
In fact when I print is type in the console it is given as a closed 'object' while if I ask the type of something like:

```
var json = {"items":[{"Desc":"Item1"},{"Desc":"Item2"},{"firstName":"John"},{"lastName":"Smith"}]};
```

it is:

> Object {firstName: Array(2), lastName: Array(2)}

Consequently if I stringfy the json variable the correct string is created, while if I do it on my [] delimited structure it creates an empty.
How may I correctly handle a dictionary expressed as a {} delimited structure?

Comment: Don't confuse the output formatting that the `console` routines use with what's actually going on with your values. The console shows you things in a way it imagines to be helpful with debugging, and different consoles do different things.

Comment: Also that first block of code you posted doesn't really make sense. The loop constructs an object and assigns it to `newValue` but then it does not *use* `newValue`.

Comment: problem is you are assigned `0` and not `newValue`. Thats why the array doesn't contain the 'objects' like you expect

Comment: In your code that builds the dictionary you don't do anything with newValue

Answer (score 1):

The issue was simply due to how I initalized the variable. It was to be:

```
$scope.lastValues={};
```

rather than:
    $scope.lastValues=[];

This latter form worked fine everywhere rather than when trying to stringfy it.